# Error when using table( , sum()). Arguments not same length?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a table that has two columns. The first column has the file number, and the second column is the number of complete cases in each file.

I managed to write up a function that processed the individual files that I need into a data frame (almost entirely taken from Coursera). I was able to use this function to find the mean of specific columns, so I assume it works.

However, I am getting the error that my arguments do not have the same length. Also, the table doesn't look like how I want it to look. I was wondering whether someone could take a look at it, and point me in the right direction.

Anyway, here is my code, and the error that comes up:

```
to.use <- list.files('specdata', full.names = TRUE)
all.data <- data.frame()
complete.table <- data.frame()
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
                for (i in id) {
                  all.data <- rbind(all.data, read.csv(to.use[i]))
                }
            subset_ad <- all.data[which(all.data[,"ID"] %in% id),]
            table(id, "nobs" = sum(complete.cases(subset_ad)))
}
```

```
> complete("specdata", 1)
   nobs
id  117
  1   1
> complete("specdata", c(2,4,8,10,12))
Error in table(id, nobs = sum(complete.cases(subset_ad))) : 
  all arguments must have the same length
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone who came across this and was interested in a (partial?) answer, I managed to re-work my situation and complete this part of the assignment.

Here is the final code and final result.

```
to.use <- list.files('specdata', full.names = TRUE)
all.data <- data.frame()
comp_cas <- data.frame()
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
                for (i in id) {
                  all.data <- rbind(all.data, read.csv(to.use[i]))
                  subset_ad <- subset(all.data, ID %in% i)
                  comp_cas <- rbind(comp_cas, as.numeric(summary(complete.cases(subset_ad))[3]))
                }
                  cbind(id, "nobs" = unlist(comp_cas, use.names = FALSE))
}
```

```
complete("specdata", 1)
complete("specdata", c(2,4,8,10,12))
complete("specdata", 30:25)
complete("specdata", 3)

     id nobs
[1,]  1  117
     id nobs
[1,]  2 1041
[2,]  4  474
[3,]  8  192
[4,] 10  148
[5,] 12   96
     id nobs
[1,] 30  932
[2,] 29  711
[3,] 28  475
[4,] 27  338
[5,] 26  586
[6,] 25  463
     id nobs
[1,]  3  243
```